# phpqrcode - save file to temporary directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, qr-code, temporary, temp

I'm trying to create a QR-code with the php library [phpqrcode](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/).

I want to save the file in a temporary file so  I can use it afterwards. Something like [this](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=005).

I'm using the Zend Framework and want to use the temporary directory. This is what I have so far:

```
require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
require_once 'phpqrcode/qrconfig.php';

$tempDir = '/temp';

$fileName = 'test'.'.png';

$pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir . $fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = '/temp' . $fileName;

// generating
if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    QRcode::png('http://mylink.com/s/'.$quiz_url, $pngAbsoluteFilePath, 'L', 4, 2);
    echo 'File generated!';
    echo '<hr />';
} else {
    echo 'File already generated! We can use this cached file to speed up site on common codes!';
    echo '<hr />';
}

echo 'Server PNG File: '.$pngAbsoluteFilePath;
echo '<hr />';

// displaying
echo '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';
```

My output shows:

> Server PNG File: /temptest.png

And an image that can't be found. Can somebody help me on the way?

EDIT:
When I tried to change the '/temp' to '/temp/' I get this warning:

```
Warning: imagepng(/temp/test.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/surveyanyplace/site/library/phpqrcode/qrimage.php on line 43
```

**SECOND EDIT:**
When I checked my hard drive I saw that he just saves images on my root map like 'temptest.png'... How can I make sure he save this on temp folder on my server?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change `$tempDir` to `/temp/` (with a trailing slash)?

Comment: Then I get a warning like tis: Warning: imagepng(/temp/test.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/surveyanyplace/site/library/phpqrcode/qrimage.php on line 43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image can't be found by your browser because it's looking for it at the URL "http://domain.tld/temptest.png" which relates to location "*/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/surveyanyplace/site/public/temptest.png*" on your disk and is not where the file was saved (it's "*/temptest.png*" as you noticed).

In order to directly serve files via your web server (Apache) you have to make sure the image file is under it's `DocumentRoot` (typically the "public" folder of your Zend Framework application)

One way is to create the following directory : "*/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/surveyanyplace/site/public/qrcodecaches*" and change `$pngAbsoluteFilePath` and `$urlRelativeFilePath` as follows:

```
$pngAbsoluteFilePath = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/qrcodecaches/' . $fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = '/qrcodecaches/' . $fileName;
```

(`$tempDir` can be removed)

NB: You might want to take a look to [Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) to make `$urlRelativeFilePath` more portable when dealing with applications inside a subdirectory